# Producing html using javascript difficulties

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Currently have problem when I produce html using a javascript. Below is my code:

html:

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

javascript:

```
var html = '';          
for(var i=0; i < 2; i++){
    html += '<button onclick="#" class="btn btn-default kiosk_btn">button</button>'
}         
$( "#result" ).html( html );
```

css:

```
.kiosk_btn{font-size: 4vmin; background-color: #141E26; border:none; box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px black; margin: 2vmin; height:8vmin; width:80vmin; color:white;}
.kiosk_btn:active{outline: none; text-decoration: none;}
.kiosk_btn:focus{outline: none; text-decoration: none; }
.kiosk_btn:hover{text-decoration: none; background-color: #213140; color:white;}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/y58pqdvt/)

I'm using the bootstrap buttons. The buttons will become white after pressing it. It is supposed to go back to original color after pressing it.

If I straightaway write the button as html coding instead of using javascript, it will not have such problem. Do you guys have any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the bootstrap CSS rule

```
.btn-default:focus {
    ...
}
```

There are two solutions.

1st solution : use `!important` on `kiosk_btn color and backroud-color`, be carefull about it.

```
.kiosk_btn{font-size: 4vmin; background-color: #141E26 !important; border:none; box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px black; margin: 2vmin; height:8vmin; width:80vmin; color:white !important;}
```

2nd solution, override the bootstrap css rule

```
.kiosk_btn:focus{outline: none; text-decoration: none; background-color: #141E26;color:white;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the focus rule, just override it

```
.kiosk_btn:focus {
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #141E26;
    color:white;
}
```

```js
var html = '';
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  html += '<button class="btn btn-default kiosk_btn">button</button>'
}

$("#result").html(html);
```

```css
.kiosk_btn {
  font-size: 4vmin;
  background-color: #141E26;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px black;
  margin: 2vmin;
  height: 8vmin;
  width: 80vmin;
  color: white;
}
.kiosk_btn:active {
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.kiosk_btn:focus {
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #141E26;
  color: white;
}
.kiosk_btn:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #213140;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you've clicked on the button, it becomes `focus`ed.

And Bootstrap defined this :

```
.btn-default:focus {
    color: #333;
    background-color: #ebebeb;
    border-color: #adadad
}
```

Just overload your `.kiosk_btn:focus` and it should fix the problem.

By the way, I get the same problem when adding the buttons "manually" in the html.